# How to get intent.getExtras from notification.addaction to work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have made a very simple app and put one icon on notification.

Now, i want to put a stop button inside the notification, so i've started to use .addaction

But when i try to pass this pIntentStop that goes with the extra data, i can't recover it in the "on new intent"

I'm using singleInstance.

This file is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Notification noti;
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Intent intentStop = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intentStop.putExtra("method", "openStop");
    PendingIntent pIntentStop = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intentStop, 0);

    noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.resume))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(R.drawable.shutdown, this.getString(R.string.stop),
                    pIntentStop).setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    noti.flags |= Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    super.onPause();
}

public void openStop(View v) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Intent sender = getIntent();
    String extraData = sender.getExtras().getString("method");
    if (intent.getExtras() != null && extraData.equals("openStop")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "method: " + extraData);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to start an activity to remove a notification only to immediately call finish and add the notification back?

Comment: I would use a service to cancel the notification.

Comment: I Just want to make openStop be called by the .addaction intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i put public static final String ACTION_STOP = "STOP"; as global and the rest:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Intent intentStop = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intentStop.setAction(MainActivity.ACTION_STOP);

    PendingIntent pIntentStop = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intentStop, 0);

    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(this.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.resume))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .addAction(R.drawable.shutdown, this.getString(R.string.stop),
                    pIntentStop).setContentIntent(pIntent).build();

    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        noti.flags |= Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    super.onPause();
}

public void openStop(View v) {
    openStop();
}

public void openStop() {
    myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    myWebView.clearCache(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
    System.exit(0);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction() != null) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(MainActivity.ACTION_STOP)) {
            this.finish();
            openStop();
        }
    }
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```